# Insert child with auto generated ids using put method in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child

I have two types in my index bearing parent-child relationship. Now I want to index child with auto generated ids, using PUT method(No _bulk API).

Without auto-generated ids, the url will look like:

```
PUT /amas/engresults/10?parent=14
```

And it's working perfectly fine.

However with auto generated ids, the urls I am trying:

```
PUT /amas/engresults/parent=14
PUT /amas/engresults?parent=14
```

But none of them are working. What should be the url for indexing child with auto generated ids?

Answer (score 1):

```
POST /amas/engresults?parent=14
{
  .....
}
```